# jQuery - How to apply addClass to only current instance?

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass

I have this code appearing hundreds of times on a page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="containerbutton"></div>
<div class="containercontent">content</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="containerbutton"></div>
<div class="containercontent">content</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="containerbutton"></div>
<div class="containercontent">content</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve this: whenever "containerbutton" is hovered, I want the "containercontent" div under it to display and have the "displayclass" class applied to it. However right now, anytime I hover over a "containerbutton" div, ALL "containercontent" divs on the page display. How can I target only the currently hovered button?

Here is the script I'm currently working with:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$(".container .containerbutton").hover(function () {
    $(".containercontent").addClass('displayclass');
    }, function(){
    $(".containercontent").removeClass('displayclass');
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `this` reference to get the current hovered element

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$(".container .containerbutton").hover(function () {
    $(this).next().addClass('displayclass');
    }, function(){
    $(this).next().removeClass('displayclass');
});

});
```

```css
.displayclass{
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="containerbutton">1</div>
<div class="containercontent">content</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="containerbutton">2</div>
<div class="containercontent">content</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="containerbutton">3</div>
<div class="containercontent">content</div>
</div>
```